# how do you send mutiple records to dynamic textboxs in flash as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, dynamic

Im creating a scoreboard within flash, ive got mysql data converted to xml and grabbed into flash, im trying to output the data: user, score, time into dynamic textboxs but can only get one record.

If you could help that would be great!

If there is a better way, such as creating the textfields on output could someone point me in the right direction!

```
    function outputXML()
    {
        for (var i=0; i<xmldata.item.length(); i++)

            myUser.text = xmldata.item[i].user;
            myScore.text = xmldata.item[i].score;
            myTime.text = xmldata.item[i].ctime;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this look?

```
    function outputXML()
    {
        myUser.text = "";
        myScore.text = "";
        myTime.text = "";
        for (var i=0; i<xmldata.item.length(); i++)

            myUser.text += xmldata.item[i].user + "\n";
            myScore.text += xmldata.item[i].score + "\n";
            myTime.text += xmldata.item[i].ctime + "\n";

        }
    }
```

Instead of just setting the text to each new record's user/score/time, I'm adding the new record's values each time (and separating them by a newline `\n`.

Comment: Ive jsut found another way using appendText; myUser.appendText(xmldata.item[i].user +"\n");